# Changing column data type to factor with sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, apache-spark-sql, sparklyr

I am pretty new to Spark and am currently using it using the R API through sparkly package. I created a Spark data frame from hive query. The data types are not specified correctly in the source table and I'm trying to reset the data type by leveraging the functions from `dplyr` package. Below is the code I tried:

```
prod_dev <- sdf_load_table(...)
num_var <-  c("var1", "var2"....)
cat_var <-  c("var_a","var_b", ...)

pos1 <- which(colnames(prod_dev) %in% num_var)
pos2 <- which(colnames(prod_dev) %in% cat_var)

prod_model_tbl <- prod_dev %>% 
                mutate(age = 2016- as.numeric(substr(dob_yyyymmdd,1,4))) %>%
                mutate(msa_fg = ifelse(is.na(msacode2000), 0, 1)) %>% 
                mutate(csa_fg = ifelse(is.na(csacode), 0, 1)) %>%
                mutate_each(funs(factor), pos2) %>%
                mutate_each(funs(as.numeric), pos1)
```

The code will work if prod_dev is a R data frame. But using it on a Spark Data frame does not seem to produce the correct result:

```
> head(prod_model_tbl)


    Source:   query [?? x 99]
    Database: spark connection master=yarn-client app=sparklyr_test local=FALSE

    Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: undefined function     FACTOR; line 97 pos 2248 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveFunctionRegistry....
```

Can someone please advise how to make the desired changes to the Spark Data Frame?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general you can use standard R generic functions for type casting. For example:

```r
df <- data.frame(x=c(1, NA), y=c("-1", "2"))

copy_to(sc, df, "df", overwrite=TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(x_char = as.character(x)) %>% 
  mutate(y_numeric = as.numeric(y))
```

```
Source:   query [2 x 4]
Database: spark connection master=...

      x     y x_char y_numeric
  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>
1     1    -1    1.0        -1
2   NaN     2   <NA>         2
```

The problem is Spark doesn't provide any direct equivalent of R `factor`.

In Spark SQL we use `double` type and column metadata to represent categorical variables and ML `Transformers`, which are not a part of SQL, for encoding. Therefore there is no place for `factor` / `as.factor`. SparkR provides some automatic conversions when working with ML but I am not sure if there is similar mechanism in `sparklyr` (the closest thing I am aware of is [`ml_create_dummy_variables`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42701698)).