# Why doesn't ml_create_dummy_variables show new dummy variable columns in sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, machine-learning, data-science, sparklyr

I'm trying to create a model matrix in sparklyr. There is a function `ml_create_dummy_variables()` for creating dummy variables for one categorical variable at a time. As far as I can tell there is no model.matrix() equivalent for creating a model matrix in one step. It's easy to use `ml_create_dummy_variables()` but I don't understand why the new dummy variables aren't stored in the Spark dataframe.

Consider this example:

```
    ###create dummy data to figure out how model matrix formulas work in sparklyr

v1 <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 50000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05))
v2 <- sample( LETTERS[5:6], 50000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7,0.3))
v3 <- sample( LETTERS[7:10], 50000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1))
v4 <- sample( LETTERS[11:15], 50000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.05,.45))
v5 <- sample( LETTERS[16:17], 50000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4,0.6))
v6 <- sample( LETTERS[18:21], 50000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.1, 0.65, 0.15))
v7 <- sample( LETTERS[22:26], 50000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.03,.02))
v8 <- rnorm(n=50000,mean=.5,sd=.1)
v9 <- rnorm(n=50000,mean=5,sd=3)
v10 <- rnorm(n=50000,mean=3,sd=.5)
response <- rnorm(n=50000,mean=10,sd=2)

dat <- data.frame(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10,response)
write.csv(dat,file='fake_dat.csv',row.names = FALSE)

#push "fake_dat.csv" to the hdfs

library(dplyr)
library(sparklyr)
#configure the spark session and connect
config <- spark_config()
config$`sparklyr.shell.driver-memory` <- "2G" #change depending on the size of the data
config$`sparklyr.shell.executor-memory` <- "2G"

sc <-  spark_connect(master='yarn-client', spark_home='/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/spark',config = config)
sc

#can also set spark_home as ‘/usr/hdp/current/spark-client’

#read in the data from the hdfs
df <- spark_read_csv(sc,name='fdat',path='hdfs://pnhadoop/user/stc004/fake_dat.csv')

#create spark table
dat <- tbl(sc,'fdat')

#create dummy variables
ml_create_dummy_variables(x=dat,'v1', reference = NULL)
```

Now I get the following notification from sparklyr:

```
Source:   query [5e+04 x 15]
Database: spark connection master=yarn-client app=sparklyr local=FALSE

      v1    v2    v3    v4    v5    v6    v7        v8        v9      v10
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1      A     F     I     O     Q     T     X 0.4518162 12.281566 3.915094
2      C     E     H     L     Q     T     X 0.3967605  2.131341 3.373347
3      C     F     I     O     P     S     W 0.4458047  7.167670 2.737003
4      C     E     G     M     P     T     X 0.4822457  5.946978 2.375309
5      B     E     H     L     P     U     W 0.4756011  9.456327 2.406996
6      C     F     H     L     P     U     X 0.5064916  2.920591 3.111827
7      C     F     I     O     Q     T     W 0.3060585  1.611517 2.242328
8      B     F     J     L     Q     T     V 0.6238052  9.821750 2.670400
9      C     E     I     O     Q     U     X 0.4249922  2.141794 3.020958
10     B     F     G     K     P     T     X 0.5348334  1.461034 3.057635
# ... with 4.999e+04 more rows, and 5 more variables: response <dbl>,
#   v1_A <dbl>, v1_B <dbl>, v1_C <dbl>, v1_D <dbl>
```

When I check the number of columns the new dummy variables don't appear.

```
> colnames(dat)
 [1] "v1"       "v2"       "v3"       "v4"       "v5"       "v6"
 [7] "v7"       "v8"       "v9"       "v10"      "response"
>
```

Why is that happening? Also, is there an easy way to convert all columns in one step? I work with datasets of >1000 variables so I need a quick way to do this.
I've tried creating a loop, but that doesn't do anything:

```
for(i in 1:7){
ml_create_dummy_variables(x=dat,colnames(dat)[i],reference=NULL)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ml_create_dummy_variables` doesn't modify existing table but create and your code simply discards the results. You have to store the results:

```
tmp <- ml_create_dummy_variables(x=dat,'v1', reference = NULL)
```

> Also, is there an easy way to convert all columns in one step? I work with datasets of >1000 variables so I need a quick way to do this

Loop or `Reduce` is just fine but there is no quick way to do it. To create dummies you have to [determine all possible levels first and this requires [a full column scan for each variable](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/blob/074bffc4d7aca0ce90f0aed5be113bcc8aba868b/R/sdf_interface.R#L442-L447).

Furthermore with > 1000 columns, especially with large number of levels you start to hit different limitations of the Spark optimizer. `sparklyr` (unlike Spark ML which uses `Vector` UDT) [expands all columns](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/blob/074bffc4d7aca0ce90f0aed5be113bcc8aba868b/R/sdf_interface.R#L463-L469) and this doesn't scale well.